# How to find the id which contains the specific name includes in it using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a excel file containing three columns as shown below,

| project_id | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 755 | Waber | 2019-04-08 |
| 755 | Wabern | 2020-06-16 |
| 755 | Wabern (FTTH geplan) | 2020-07-24 |
| 755 | Wabern FTTH DTAG | 2020-08-15 |
| 755 | Wabern (FTTH DTAG gg) | 2021-03-05 |
| 755 | Wabern | 2021-09-13 |
| 134 | Lerbeck | 2019-04-18 |
| 134 | BAd oyehausen (FttH svd) | 2020-06-26 |
| 134 | Werre Park | 2020-07-14 |
| 134 | Werre Park (FTTH ssd) | 2020-08-25 |
| 134 | Werre Park (FTTH) | 2021-03-15 |
| 134 | Bad oyehausen | 2021-09-23 |
| 584 | kitern | 2019-04-08 |
| 584 | Lausen (ftth los) | 2020-06-16 |
| 584 | kitener (FTTH geplan) | 2020-07-24 |
| 584 | Lausern | 2020-08-15 |
| 584 | Lausern (FTTH DTAG gg) | 2021-03-05 |

Is it possible to filter out the **project_id** for which the name does not include any form of  **(FTTH)** in the first row of the same id and at the last row of the same id.  For example the first **project_id** 755 in the first row doesn't have any form of (FTTH) included in it and also the last row of the same project_id doesn't have the text (fttH), but for the **project_id 584** it is a different scenario. Is it possible to filter out the project_id which doesn't include **FTTH**  in any form in the first and last row of the same project_id ?

Expecting the result to be like,

| project_id |
| --- |
| 755 |
| 134 |

Comment: would you mind adding the code you have tried so far to apply the filter?

Comment: @simpleApp, I have tried this earlier, but this doesn't give me a proper result as I was expecting a different one. 
df1 = df.groupby('project_id')['name'].agg(['first','last'])

i = df1.index[~df1['first'].str.endswith('(FTTH)') &~df1['last'].str.endswith('FTTH')]
print (i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looping over the unique id, and each time get the all name by specific id, after keep only first and last name, convert it to str and check there is any word 'FTTH'

Code:

```
import numpy as np
[i for i in set(df.id.values) if 'FTTH' not in str(np.array(df[df['id']==i]['NM'])[[0,-1]])]



#[755, 134]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas:

```py
def custom_function(series, pattern='FTTH'):
    """Identify if the first and last items do not have a pattern"""
    first = pattern not in series.iat[0].upper()
    last = pattern not in series.iat[-1].upper()
    return first and last

df.groupby('project_id').Name.apply(custom_function)
```

Output:

```
project_id
134     True
584    False
755     True
Name: Name, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

a different approuch with pandas:

```
res = df.groupby('project_id').apply(lambda x: ~x.Name.take([0,-1]).str
                                     .contains('ftth',case=False).any())

res[res].reset_index().drop(0,axis=1)

>>>
'''
    project_id
0   134
1   755
```

Comment: Why do I get **AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'**
this error ?

Comment: @Vicky, sorry i have no idea, i tested the code with data you provided and it works OK. this expression `x.Name.take([0,-1])` returns series object which do has `str` atribute, but the errore message says that you have numpy.ndarray instead of series object. So check your code for typo and so on.